# Any way to change background color of custom shape on click

Tags: java, android

I have a custom shape for my ListView background. But now it will not change color on click. Is there any way of doing this?
Here is my xml for the ListView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#ff8d8d8d"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#ff8d8d8d"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="#ff8d8d8d"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Here is the CustomShape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient android:startColor="#ffffff"
    android:endColor="#ffd6d4d6"
    android:angle="270"
/>
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a selector, but you will be chaining the whole drawable, not only the **color**. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

You can understand this list like

```
switch(state){
  case pressed:
     use some drawable
     break;
   case focused:
     use some other drawable
     break;
   default:
    use the default drawable
}
```

Comment: yes, but is there a way to do it without losing the custom shape background?

Comment: copy paste your custom shape to another xml and only change the color

Answer (score 1):

Create a [StateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) drawable with a different drawable for the pressed state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```